# Divisão contínua - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, lista

```
for i in lista:
    lista.append(X)
    X = X * 0.5

for i in range(100):
    print 'N[%d] = %.4f' %(i, lista[i])
```

Acontece sempre este erro:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Você está tentando acessar um índice que não existe na variável `lista`.

Comment: A lista e a variável "X"  não postei aqui kkk

Comment: Você pode [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/145930/edit) a pergunta e colocar se você quiser.

Comment: Isso é porque a a variável `lista` não tem 100 elementos... `experimente` fazer `print len(lista)` antes do ultimo ciclo for para ver quantos items tem. De qualquer maneira para fazer isso que está a fazer poderia ser mais direto se fizesse logo `for i in lista: ...` onde i será cada elemento que essa lista contém